# How to do arithmetic operations in binary with Java?

Tags: java, string, math, binary, arithmetic-expressions

For a Java assignment I am required to be able to pass any number that will be introduced as a string through the command line (no matter how big) into binary.

Then generate methods that will allow these numbers to add, multiply, subtract and divide.

My question would be first:

How do I make my string into binary

Eg:

123 would become 1111011

8403678 would become 100000000011101011011110

And so forth...

Then the biggest issue is to get them to add up, subtract each other, etc.

Last I need to be able to convert back the result from binary back to decimal which I am having more trouble understanding how to do it than the previous case (transforming from binary into a decimal string).

Eg:

if 1111011 was added to 100000000011101011011110 the result would be 100000000011101101011001 and then it would become 8403801 which I would print out as a result.

The final aim of this project is to create our own class such as java.math.BigInteger (without using it of course) and handling arbitrarily big numbers (bigger than what Int can handle).

If there is any extra information required please let me know I will answer promptly.

Comment: Take a look at the BigInteger class.  It'll help you get started.  AFter that think of lots of loops that divide by two and take the modulo two.

Comment: If you do this exercise you have to understand binary system and its arithmetic.  Only then you'll be ready to translate this knowledge to Java. There's plenty of information on the web.  For examaple: http://academic.evergreen.edu/projects/biophysics/technotes/misc/bin_math.htm or http://www2.cs.uregina.ca/~rbm/cs100/notes/binary/binary.html

Comment: The final aim of this project is to create our own class such as java.math.BigInteger (without using it ofcourse) and handling arbitrarily big numbers (bigger than what Int can handle).

Answer (score 0):

Since you have to be able to handle large numbers without using BigInteger, you need to find a way to represent arbitrarily large numbers. Obviously `int` will not do. One easy way is to represent the number as a String. For instance, the number 123 could be stored as the String "123".

Converting to binary will require some intermediate operations such as division and modulo. Thus, it is worth thinking about how to do these when your numbers are stored in Strings. Since this is homework I don't want to just give you the answer, but some guidance instead.

Say you want to do addition.

1. Think about how you add big numbers by hand. Which digits of each number do you use, and how do you manipulate them to get the answer? This algorithm is fairly straightforward, and once you can explain it, you can give a computer directions to do it as well. (For addition, you add first the one's digits, then the ten's digits, etc... and remember to carry if you have to!)
2. Note that you can get the digits of your number String by using a method such as `charAt(int n)`. This will return the character at index n of the string. Convert it to an Integer by using `Integer.parseInt()` (which takes a numeric string and converts it to an integer).
3. So now you can think: If I want the one's digit of a number, what index would that be in a String? Starting with this, you should be able to figure out how to get any digit you want from a big number string. Now, you can implement your algorithm.

Finally, to convert from base ten to binary you do need to understand how number bases work. This gives a clear and quick introduction: http://www.math.grin.edu/~rebelsky/Courses/152/97F/Readings/student-binary 
The section "Converting from decimal to binary" in the above link describes a method for exactly what you want to do. Good luck.